# Django ModelForm exclude data saving

Tags: django

Trying to save data with login user. Tried as below.

models.py

```
class MyModel(TimeStamped):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['user']
```

views.py

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm()
    else:
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Message Sent Successfully')
            redirect('home')
    return render(request, "add.html", {'form': form})
```

It saved data. But problem is user is not setting to login user. Tried adding in view `form.user = request.user`. still is not saving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm()
    else:
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Message Sent Successfully')
            redirect('home')
    return render(request, "add.html", {'form': form})
```